# Does anyone know why I am getting this APEX interactive report/X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff issue or how I can resolve it?

Tags: apex, oracle-apex-20.1

Hi I have a sandbox environment that we are using to test how our apps will act in APEX 20.1 (All Apps are from version 19.1) but we seem to have a few issues with some areas and getting a identical or similar error as follows

X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff X-Xss-Protection:1; mode=block X-ORACLE-IGNORE: IGNORE X-ORACLE-IGNORE: IGNORE X-ORACLE-IGNORE: IGNORE Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-length: 21983

I have tried searching the knowledge base for further information but I must not be doing a search on the right subject as not a lot is related to what I am experiencing so wanted to reach out to an expert for further clarification.

This is also affecting all interactive reports so i am assuming this might be an incorrect setting at the either admin or instance/app server level can anyone confirm if there is something that might be causing this and how to resolve the issue? Many thanks.

I have also included a screenshot of the error on one of the interactive reports

[image: Apex error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regression in the APEX 20.1 bundle patch, and is specific to the use of mod_plsql. This fix is now part of the APEX 20.1 PSE (Patch Set Exception) bundle.

If you go to My Oracle Support, download patch 30990551, and apply it - it should resolve this issue. We are in the process of updating the [APEX 20.1 Known Issues](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/apex-downloads/apex-201-known-issues.html) to include this specific fix.

Please note - this bug will still be present in APEX 20.2. And thus, before you move to APEX 20.2 or higher, you will need to exclusively use Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) and not Apache/mod_plsql. For APEX 20.2 and higher, [ORDS is the only supported Web listener](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/oracle-rest-data-services-the-only-supported-web-listener-for-oracle-apex) for APEX.

Joel